# Need help on simple calculator

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function fadd()
{
var first,sec,res;
first=parsefloat(document.forms[0].txt1st.value);
sec=parsefloat(document.forms[0].txt2nd.value);
res=first+sec;
document.forms[0].txtres.value=res;
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form>
Enter 1st number &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="txt1st" id="txt1st" type="text">
</br>
Enter 2nd number &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="txt2nd" id="txt2nd" type="text">
</br>
Result &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="txtres" id="txtres" type="text">
</br>
<input name="btnadd" id="btnadd" type="button" value="+" onclick="fadd()">
<input name="btnsub" id="btnsub" type="button" value="-" onclick="fminus()">
<input name="btndiv" id="btndiv" type="button" value="%" onclick="fdiv()">
<input name="btnmul" id="btnmul" type="button" value="*" onclick="fmult()">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This answer was posted before the question was updated.

You cannot use the dot notation for property names that start with a number.

Don't use `document.forms[0].1st`. Use `document.getElementById('1st')`. The same applies for `2nd`.

```
var x = {};

x['1st'] = 10;

console.log(x['1st']); // This works
console.log(x.1st);    // This doesn't - Syntax error
```

Comment: @Gaby: Yes, good point... In addition, there's also the `parseFloat` problem as [@strager identified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361694/need-help-on-simple-calculator/3361717#3361717)

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

`parsefloat` should be `parseFloat`.  Function names are case-sensitive.

`1st` is not a legal ID (and I don't think it's a legal name, either).  Also, you cannot refer to a non-identifier (`1st` is not an identifier because it begins with a digit) in dot notation (`x.y.z`).  You could try `document.forms[0]['1st'].value`, or you could try renaming `1st` to `first` (and `2nd` to `second`).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should change this line:

```
document.forms[0].textres.value=res;
```

To this:

```
document.forms[0].txtres.value=res;
```

After listening to the advice of the other posts here AND doing this, your code should work fine.